# Does mysql return data on demand, or all? Why looping over the data is slower than accessing them?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, select, hash

I was wondering when we call the perl dbi apis to query a database, are *all* the results return? Or do we get partially the result set and as we iterating we retrieve more and more rows from the database.
The reason I am asking is that I notice the following in a perl script.
I did a query to a database which returns a really large number of records. After getting this records I did a `for` loop over the results and created a `hash` of this data.
What I noticed is that the actual query from the database return in a reasonable amount of time (the results were a lot) **but** the big delay was looping over the data to create the hash.
I don't understand this. I would expect that the query would be the slow part since the for loop and the construction of the hash would be in-memory and would be cheap.
Any explanation/idea why this happens? Am I misunderstanding something basic here?
**Update**
I understand that MySQL caches data so when I run the same query multiple times it would be faster the second time and on. But still I would not expect the for loop over the data set in memory to be of the same (and more) time duration as the query to the MySQL DB.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using DBD::mysql, the default is to pull all the results from the server at once and store them in memory. This avoids tying up the server's resources and works fine for the majority of result sets as RAM is usually plentiful.

That answers your original question, but if you would like more assistance, I suggest pasting code - it's possible your hash building code is doing something wrong, or unnecessary queries are being made. See also [Speeding up the DBI](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Speeding%20up%20the%20DBI) for tips on efficient use of the DBI API, and how to profile what DBI is doing.

Comment: I would paste the code but it is too straight forward.I mean there is *no* extra query to the DB made in the loop. I just create a an array of anonymous hashes based on the data I got from the DB